# Access Denied on South West Airlines

Tags: geolocation

When going to the South West airlines homepage, I'm consistently getting:

> HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden - Access Denied: You don't have permission to access
>   "http://www.southwest.com/" on this server. Reference #(Long number).

Is this related to GDPR? I've seen several newspaper articles mentioning this. I'm outside the US, and tried this both from home and from a Linux server in another non-US country.

Comment: What browser are you using? Have you tried a different browser? What country are you viewing from? What other country did you try from? The site appears to work in the UK.

Comment: Safari, Chrome. The Netherlands and another European country.

Comment: Your title should attract some readers.  I thought the question was about you're not being allowed to board a plane.  :-)

Comment: @fixer1234: That's hilarious. And ironically, you're right. They seem to deny a lot of people access on their planes.

Answer (score 1):

It's not likely that this is GDPR related ... on Southwest's site there are threads with complaints about this problem going back at least to 2016.

https://www.southwestaircommunity.com/t5/General-Travel-Policies/Website-access/td-p/47364

The thread title says "Solved: Website access ..." but I don't see any "solution" (unless you consider calling Southwest on the phone from halfway around the world a solution).

Comment: Yes, I saw those too, but it seemed sort of a coincidence that this happened in these days of GDPR (though I've never been to that site before). The reason I went there is because I heard they had done great work with simplifying air travel. Inexplicably shutting users out of your site would be a fly in that ointment.